# How to display data from source table in JSON response with Hibernate @ManyToOne relation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I make internet shoe shop with Spring Boot + Hibernate + PostgreSQL and there are tables Goods with info about shoe and Sizes table which contains info about concrete shoe sizes and quantity in stock. So table with goods will contain info about its sizes. Table Sizes contains foreign key to Id in Goods and I want Hibernate to parse JSON that will contain sizes either

relations from Good entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Good {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private sexType sexType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "ManufacturerId")
    @JsonManagedReference //-------------------------------------------------------
    Manufacturer manufacturer; //Many goods can refer to one manufacturer

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "good")  //Uni-directional reference to size array
            //@JoinColumn(name= "goodid")
    List<Size> sizes; //Refactor to bi-directional relationship

    public void addSizeToGood(Size size) {
        if (sizes == null) sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        sizes.add(size);
        //size.setGood(this);
    }
```

Size entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sizes")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Size {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "Size")
    private int size;

    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "goodid")
    private int goodId;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "goodId")
    Good good;
```

DAO method that returns list of goods

```
@Repository
public class GoodDAOImpl implements GoodDAO{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional //Spring open and close transactions automatically
    public List<Good> getAllGoods() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        //Query<Good> query = session.createQuery("from Good", Good.class);
        Query<Good> query = (Query<Good>) entityManager.createQuery("from Good right join Size on Good.");
        List<Good> allGoods = query.getResultList();

        return allGoods;
    }
}
```

[DB architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfxQf.png)
[JSON response w/o info about sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAgBh.png)

I tried to use sophisticated query hql code and used multiple hibernate annotations but nothing goood happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `@JsonBackReference` in `sizes` attributes, and `@JsonManagedReference` in Size class, into good attribute. You can change one annotation by the other one. See this link: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

> **@JsonManagedReference** is the forward part of reference, the one that **gets serialized** normally.
>
> **@JsonBackReference** is the back part of reference; **it'll be omitted from serialization**.

If you need in some cases show Size object and its good related attribute, you can create a SizeDto and you can include different annotations there.